# A website page displays "{ }" but works on localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I am using ReactJS for my website and it is deployed through Firebase hosting. One of the pages of the website displays "{ }" on the hosting domain, but it runs fine on localhost. There are no errors on the console.

I redeployed it multiple times, and all the other pages are working fine so I don't think it is a deployment issue either.

It also works fine if I manually navigate to this page from the site (on the hosted domain), but if I refresh this page afterward, or try to open this page by directly entering the URL, it shows "{ }" again.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

EDIT: This issue was resolved after I changed my route name from `/post/:ID` to `/post-detail/:ID`. I didn't have any other route which had similar name as `/post`, so why wasn't it working before? And why was it still working on localhost?

Comment: People looking at this question would be as clueless as you. This question itself is vague and ambiguous. There's no code or a reproducible example; it'd be tough to get help

Comment: @boop_the_snoot I'm hoping someone might have run into a similar problem sometime. I can share the code for the page but I really don't think it will make a difference, since this is working on localhost without any errors.

Comment: With the given information, in my opinion this points to some kind of routing problem on the front-end with the `react-router`, but that is blindfolded shot... you need to provide code, i think a good starting point should be your `App.js`, `index.js`, `firebase.js`, `package.json` and the code of one working page along with the page code of the not working one...

Comment: @DobromirKirov you're right, it had to do with routing. I change the route name from "/post/:ID" to "/post-detail/:ID" and it worked. I don't understand why though. There isn't any other route relating to "/post". Any idea why this was happening?

Comment: As i read this the first thing that comes to my mind is some kind of confusion in the build process/react router/firebase from the thing that there is a POST method for fetching data, but this may be tottaly wrong so dont rely on it...

Comment: @DobromirKirov that is a possibility. Thank you!

Comment: Without any [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is basically just anyone's guess as to why any routing might not be working as expected.